# Table with relation to two others (three-way relation?)

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, eav, relations

I stumbled across a weird situation that one table has relation to two others but record in it can only have a relation to one of the tables. To clarify things, I have tables: `attribute`, `visit`, `visit_action`. `visit` is a parent of `visit_action` - on one visit a user can perform multiple actions. Both visits and actions have attributes that are made of `name` and `value`. One `attribute` can be related either to `visit` or `visit_action` but never to both at the same time. One visit can contain of multiple attributes and so does action. How should I keep those relations in database?

**Option 1**
Create two connecting tables like `visit_attribute` and `visit_action_attribute` both with relations to `attribute` but one with relation to `visit` and one to `visit_action`. The problem I have with this solution is that a attribute can end up being tied up to both `visit` and `visit_action` at the same time and I do not want that.
[image: two connecting tables]

**Option 2**
Create columns with `id_visit` and `id_visit_action` directly in `attribute` table. It seems like a good fit because `attribute` can't be related to many visits or actions but there is still problem that it can end up being tied up to one visit and one action at the same time. It feels bad that too one column in `attribute` table will always be `NULL` (either `id_visit` or `id_visit_action`).
[image: connections in attribute table]

Comment: I went with option 3 as thanks to that I will be sure that each attribute is connected only to `visit` or `visit_action` and not both, thank you @RDFozz.

Comment: EAV schema has a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third option:

Create tables `visit_attribute` and `visit_action_attribute` with `name` and `value` columns in each (and drop the `attribute` table altogether).

This removes the possibility of a given attribute being linked to both a `visit` and a `visit_action`, with no need for id columns with NULL values.